# How to run this code only one time in app install ?

Tags: android

how to addfirst time app install code to this code link ?
[How to add a ShowcaseView that pops up only for the first time to show how to use our app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248682/how-to-add-a-showcaseview-that-pops-up-only-for-the-first-time-to-show-how-to-us)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if android app is the first time used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)

Comment: Nobody is going to tell exact code. please provide me by editing that mainActivity.class file

Comment: don`t asking code..we are not write project for you..only we give ideas & links.

Comment: I tried it bruh using your links and stuffs. I want to fit with that mainAvtivity class. if you dont know dont help. Thankss

Answer (score 1):

Two ways...

► Create a database (SQLite for example) and put on it a boolean value to know if first time or not.

► Or use shared preferences like a database

Comment: I dont know how to deal with it . Please edit that mainActivity.class file and provide me

Comment: wait... i'll do a example

Comment: ARGGG SOF BUGS ... cant edit, cant post new ansewer :(

Comment: yeah ... whats your mail ?

Comment: You can email me here pbhusal10@gmail.com

Comment: How can i fit with that code ? Sorry i tried it but i failed.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my own app by storing a flag in the preferences.  Others have up-voted this approach too:

[Determine if android app is the first time used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636141/determine-if-android-app-is-the-first-time-used)

Comment: CAn you provide code to edit that main activity class ?

Comment: I want that popup screen appears only one timein install ? please help me out